# Insert at line number with 1 command in VIM

Tags: vim

Is there a shortcut in vim for `:20` followed by `i`, i.e. one command for inserting at a line number?

Comment: This is about how to do programming with a particular tool; it is within scope for SO.

Comment: why would you hard code a particular line number in a command?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nmap` vim command like this:

```
:nmap ~! 20Gi
```

And then every time you will press keystrokes `~!` (or you can choose any other key combination) it will move cursor on line # 20 in insert mode.

Comment: Note that if option `startofline` is unset, `G` preserves the cursor column, therefore, `i` could start Insert mode not necessarily on the first non-blank character of the line.  In this particular case it's better to use `I` or `gI` command (depending on whether you want to insert a line number before of after possible leading whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

You can type `:20i<enter>Text you want to insert including newlines...<esc>`

Comment: how is this different than what she is trying not to do? I thought he was looking for an easier way of inserting text at line N without `:Ni`, in this case line 20. Did I misinterpret the question?

Comment: This is the same number of characters typed as if you invert the order of the 'enter' and 'i' as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

another way to do what you ask is `20Gi` in normal mode. it may not be faster, but it may be easier to remember. if you want to do it without the shift try `20ggi`

thinking about it more, and this wont work in obvious cases, but I like to do the following

```
:set mouse=a
:nmap <2-LeftMouse> i
```

which, in normal mode (note `nmap`), will bring me to that line and when I double click it will change to insert on the specified line. The usefulness could be trivial, but if you are used to using the mouse this map help.

[image: http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif]

[viemu.com](http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html)has a half decent cheatsheet, if you like

Comment: This is actually one character shorter than the original; well done.

Answer (score 0):

Normal mode `i` is available in command mode as `startinsert`, but that doesn’t accept a line number. So you need two commands, and a bar to separate them, which gives you `:20 | startinsert`.

Comment: That doesn't look shorter than the original.

Comment: No, it’s just the only approach that works in vimscript, if that’s what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: In that case, you need to expand your answer to explain what you mean, because it is not entirely clear to me what you do mean; I've not encountered vimscript before, but I only use vim as a souped-up vi, not making full use of the incredible complexities it has added.